# Where is the code for ollytlscatch?

Tags: ollydbg, debuggers, anti-debugging, digital-forensics

I've been trying to get antiResHacker.exe as mentioned in this question:

[How to prevent use of Resource editors](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/how-to-prevent-use-of-resource-editors)

However, the codebase for ollytlscatch (https://code.google.com/p/ollytlscatch/) seems to be inaccessible. Is there a canonical location for this set of tools or are they no longer in public circulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for TLSCatch can be downloaded from:

- https://myollyplugins.googlecode.com/files/TLSCatch.rar

And the binary for it can be downloaded from these two locations:

- https://myollyplugins.googlecode.com/files/TLSCatch.dll
- http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/images/Bin_ollytlscatch_2010-11-3_19.7_TlsCatch.zip

Furthermore, you can download sample programs to test TLSCatch from:

- https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://ollytlscatch.googlecode.com/files/*